# Footer Div not extending entire length of Div

Tags: html, css, position, materialize

I am trying to create a footer for my simple webpage and am having some trouble with an element, which is over extending over the edge of the container. I assume this is a problem with the width.

[image]
I am trying to get the `<hr>` tag to extend the entirety of the width of the column. For reference I am using the MaterializeCSS framework for the containers, rows and columns.

---

## **Code**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"><!-- Other Content --></div>
  <div class="row"><!-- Other Content --></div>
  <div class="row"><!-- Other Content --></div>
  <div class="footer-message">
    <hr>
    Made with <span style="color: #e25555;">&hearts;</span> by Adam
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-message{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding:5px;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

I am using a position of absolute to enable to align it to the bottom of the screen and I set the width to be 100% as I understand that it would inherit the width of the parent which in this case, is a `div` with a class of `container`.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Edit: Old screenshot
 [image: Problem screenshot]

Comment: Post all the relevant code please

Comment: Which part specifically do you need? I did not include most of the row content as I did not think they would be relevant. Most of the CSS are stylings of buttons, headers, etc.

Comment: The part that you provided does not reproduce the error.

Comment: My mistake! My browser cached the old CSS file. With the code above, the error was actually the <hr> tag extending to over the edge of the screen. I have updated the post with the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to the Container, then add `left: 0; right: 0` to `footer-message` class.
Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS Grid for this, see the following snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

article {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

header {
  background: #5170a9;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main {
  color: #444;
  padding: 1rem;
}

footer {
  background: #182f58;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    Page Header
  </header>
  <main>
   Hi, there's not much content, yet. You can write in here to expand the container.
  </main>
  <footer>
    All rights reversed.
    <br>
    I am always at the bottom of the page
  </footer>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

make your footer like in the materialize documentation example: https://materializecss.com/footer.html

```
  <footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
        © 2014 Copyright Text
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it, but your code without the CSS works fine for me. I am not sure if you want the `<hr>` to fill the whole width of just the container width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Other Content -->
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Other Content -->
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Other Content -->
      </div>
      <div class="footer-message">
        <hr>
        Made with <span style="color: #e25555;">&hearts;</span> by Adam
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>


  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```